# Calculating average distance between maxima

Tags: code-request

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to analyze some simple data. When graphed, the data I have make a somewhat sinusoidal curve. What I want to do is to find the x-values of the maximum peaks of the sinusoidal curve. I then want to subtract each of these x-values from the last peak found and average these differences to obtain an average distance between peaks. Is there an easy way to do this with  *Mathematica* ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have the data as a discrete series of values, or as a known function _f(x)_?

Comment: It's a discrete series of values. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 12):

Generating test data

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x] + Sin[3. x/2]}, {x, 0, 6. Pi, Pi/5.}];

Clear[f]
```

The interpolation function for the data is

```
f = Interpolation[data];
```

Maxima occur for `f'[x] == 0` and `f''[x] < 0`

```
xValues = x /. Select[
   FindRoot[f'[x], {x, #}] & /@
      Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi/4] //
     Union[#, SameTest ->
        (Abs[#1[[1, -1]] - #2[[1, -1]]] < 10^-4 &)] & //
    Quiet,
   f''[x] < 0 /. # &]
```

> {1.24252, 5.65487, 8.96826, 13.8089, 18.2264}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ xValues]}]
```

[image]

The separation between the maxima are

```
diff = Differences[xValues]
```

> {4.41235, 3.31339, 4.84063, 4.41748}

Their average is

```
mu = Mean[diff]
```

> 4.24596

EDIT: However, this can be done more efficiently, particularly if the list is long. Looking at symbolic data,

```
dataS = Array[d, 10]
```

> {d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liE5G.png), d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7], d[8], d[9], d[10]}

```
dataS // Differences // Mean
```

> 1/9 (-d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liE5G.png) + d[10])

So the `Mean` of the `Differences` just divides the interval into equal subintervals.

```
% == (dataS[[-1]] - dataS[[1]])/(Length[dataS] - 1)
```

> True

```
mu == (xValues[[-1]] - xValues[[1]])/(Length[xValues] - 1)
```

> True

Answer (score 12):

Using Bob Hanlon's example data:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x] + Sin[3. x/2]}, {x, 0, 6. Pi, Pi/5.}];

peaks = FindPeaks[data[[All,2]]][[All,1]]
(* {3,10,15,23,30} *)

Mean@Differences@peaks
(* 27/4 *)

Mean@Differences@data[[peaks, 1]]
(* 4.24115 *)
```

Or, use `PeakDetect`:

```
Mean @ Differences @ Pick[#1, PeakDetect @ #2, 1] & @@Transpose[data]
(* 4.24115 *)
```

Or, using @Michael Seifert's observation, you can also use

```
Subtract @@ data[[peaks[[{-1, 1}]], 1]]/(Length[peaks] - 1)
(* 4.24115 *)
```

Plots:

```
ListLinePlot[data,Epilog->{PointSize[Large], Red, Point@data[[peaks]]}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
  Epilog->{PointSize[Large], Red, Point@data[[peaks]],
     NumberLinePlot[Interval/@Partition[data[[peaks,1]],2,1],
  PlotStyle->Thickness[.01],Spacings->0][[1]]}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize->400, 
 Epilog->{PointSize[Large], Red, Point@data[[peaks]]},
 Prolog->{NumberLinePlot[Interval/@
   Partition[data[[Join[{1},peaks,{Length[data]}],1]],2,1],
   PlotStyle-> Directive[PointSize[0], Opacity[.4], CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[1]], 
   Spacings->0][[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for introdrucing `FindPeaks` in combination with the elegant `Part`  notation.

Comment: Woah! That exists!?

Comment: @eldo thank you. Ivan it is one of those  new-in version-10 things. So is `NumberLinePlot`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm having trouble getting FindPeaks[] to work with the 2D data I have ({x0,y0},{x1,y1}, etc.). Do you know a way to get it to work?

Comment: @Evan, afaik `FindPeaks` and `PeakDetect` works only with a one-dimensional  list as the first argument. Can't think of how to use `FindPeaks`  to identify peaks in 2D data off the top of my head. That would make a great new question though.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a precisely interpolated maximum value, you can just use the data set directly, as follows:

```
values = sampledata[[;; , 2]];
diffs = Differences[values];
selector = Table[If[diffs[[i]] > 0 && diffs[[i + 1]] < 0, 1, 0], {i, 1, 
    Length[diffs] - 1}];
maxima = Pick[Drop[Drop[sampledata, 1], -1], selector, 1]
avgmaxdist = (Last[maxima][[1]] - First[maxima][[1]])/(Length[maxima] - 1)
```

The idea here is to just calculate the differences between successive data points, and then look in the differences array for all of the positive elements that are followed by a negative element.  Applying this to Bob Hanlon's sample data set yields

> {{1.25664, 1.90211}, {5.65487, 0.221232}, {8.79646, 1.17557}, {13.823,
>      1.90211}, {18.2212, 0.221232}}
>
> 4.24115

The differing results are almost certainly due to the lack of interpolation in my code.

Note that the "average distance between maxima" is really the $x$-distance between the first and the last maximum, divided by the number of gaps between maxima.  You still need to find all the maxima, though, so that you know how many there are.